# Which books are easier than Lang's Algebra for learning Category Theory?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I graduated Math BSc two years ago and I'm looking to start learning about category theory solo. I started to go through Lang's algebra and although I already learned about groups, normal groups etc in University, I'm having a hard time doing the exercises. Is there any more basic book for this book and other books about category theory (which is the subject I took Lang's for)?

Comment: I liked this one: https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Chapter-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics/dp/0821847813

Comment: I don't think Lang's _Algebra_ is about category theory. It is about algebra.

Comment: What do 'groups, normal groups, etc.' have to do with category theory?

Comment: @Somos, it's not only about category theory, but it was recommended in a different question. Reading the TOC, you are right, there's nothing specially about category theory. I'll have a look on david-wheeler's suggestion

Comment: @anomaly I think they are used as examples, no? From my low understanding in category theory, every mathematical object has something to do with category theory.

Comment: @DavidWheeler thanks! I'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

After going through the first chapters of Algebra: Chapter 0 as per @DavidWheeler's suggestion, I can say this answers my question. It has a very refreshing view of the algebra world, and it explains everything using categories. I'm really enjoying it and I'm getting all the review I need.